# Can I change the Perl 6 slang inside a method?

Tags: regex, raku

A Perl 6 [Regex](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Regex) is a more specific type of [Method](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Regex), so I had the idea that maybe I could do something black-magicky in a regular method that produces the same thing. I particularly am curious about doing this without changing any grammars.

However, looking at [Perl6/Grammar.nqp](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp) (which I barely understand), that this is really not an inheritance thing. I think, based on my reading, that the Perl 6 grammar switches slangs (sub languages) when it sees one of the regex declarators. That is, a different grammar parses the guts of `regex { ... }` and `method {...}`.

So, first, is that right?

Then, just for giggles, I thought that maybe I could be inside a method block but tell it to use a different slang (see for instance, ["Slangs" from the 2013 Perl 6 Advent Calendar](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/day-16-slangs/) or ["Slangs Today"](https://mouq.github.io/slangs.html)).

However, everything I've found looks like it wants to change the grammar. Is there a way to do it without that and return a string that is treated as if it had come out of `regex { ... }`?

```
method actually-returns-a-regex {
     ...
     }
```

I don't have any practical use for this. I just keep wondering about it.

Comment: "So, first, is that right (that) a different grammar parses the guts of regex { ... } and method {...} (?)" Yes, the `MAIN` P6 slang/grammar parses the body of a `method` declaration but uses the `Regex` slang/grammar to parse the body of a `regex` declaration.

Comment: "maybe I could be inside a method block but tell it to use a different slang" You could, but using a slang means changing the grammar(s) the compiler is using and you wrote that you don't want to change the grammar.

Comment: But, could I tell it to use an existing grammar that already does what I want?

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. (Which is why I didn't attempt an answer. Your response to moritz has left me more confused.) Some guesses to try nail down what you mean: 1) "could I" implies sanely; 2) "it" is the compiler; 3) the "existing grammar" is part of a grammar/actions pair designed to extend/bend P6; 4) what you want is what that slang does; 5) you're willing to either switch slang before compilation enters the regex body or fix up the ast afterwards. It might help if you said yes/no to each of these five guesses.

Comment: @raiph I'm slightly confused by what I want too, but it seems that the appropriate terms are overloaded to prevent me from expressing it well at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the Perl 6 design documents mandate an API where regexes return a lazy list of possible matches. If Rakudo adhered to that API, you could easily write a method that acted as a regex, but parsing would be very slow (because lazy lists tend to perform much worse than a compact list of string positions (integers) that act as a backtracking stack).

Instead, Perl 6 regexes return matches. And you can do the same. Here is an example of a method that is called like a regex inside of a grammar:

```
grammar Foo {
    token TOP { a <rest> }

    method rest() {
        if self.target.substr(self.pos, 1) eq 'b' {
            return Match.new(
                orig   => self.orig,
                target => self.target,
                from => self.pos,
                to   => self.target.chars,
            );
        }
        else {
            return Match.new();
        }
    }
}

say Foo.parse('abc');
say Foo.parse('axc');
```

Method `rest` implements the equivalent of the regex `b.*`. I hope this answers your question.

*Update*: I might have misunderstood the question. If the question is "How can I create a regex object" (and not "how can I write code that acts like a regex", as I understood it), the answer is that you have to go through the `rx//` quoting construct:

```
my $str = 'ab.*';
my $re = rx/ <$str> /;

say 'fooabc' ~~ $re;       # Output: ｢abc｣
```

Comment: I don't want to match a regex, I want to create a regex. I know my question needs some work though because it's a wonky idea and all the language we have to talk about it pushes it toward a different interpretation.

Comment: You can create regexes through the `rx//` quote operator.